# function not working multiple times?

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

This function is supposed to remove elements from a linked list. Currently it does the job however, with further testing I found out that I get a segmentation fault after using the function about 2-3 times. For example, lets say `listA` contains `1 2 3 4 4 5`, when I do `remove listA 4` and then print the elements of `listA`, the output should be `1 2 3 5`, and it is. However when I use the remove function 1-2 more times on the list, it just stops working and I keep getting segmentation faults. I'm not sure why.. Any help will be appreciated!

```
  void mylist::remove(int z)
            {       
              Node *currP, *prevP;

              prevP = NULL;
              for (currP = head; 
                   currP != NULL;
                   prevP = currP, currP = currP->next) { 

                if (currP->key == z) {
                  if (prevP == NULL) {
                    head = currP->next;
                  } else{
                    prevP->next = currP->next;
                  }
                  delete currP;
                  currP=prevP;
                  numberofnodes--;
                }
              }
              return;
         }
```

Comment: You were close to being precise, but: *"when I use the remove function 1-2 more times on the list, it just stops working"* dropped the ball.  Look into ["Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Show your exact input, and a program that compiles which anyone can copy-paste into a compiler ("complete") and can repeatedly ("verifably") give the wrong output.  Test basic cases, like removing "1" from a list containing just 1.  You might find your own problem in the process...

Comment: Just modify the update statement in for loop, access the next element from currP only when it's not NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not handling the case when first node form list is deleted, since `prevP` will be null. After deleting `currP` you are assigning `currP=prevP;`. In the next iteration when `prevP = currP, currP = currP->next` will be executed for next for-loop iteration, it will result segmentation fault.

You can use a while loop instead, like:

```
void mylist::remove(int z)
        {       
          Node *currP, *prevP, *temp;

          prevP = NULL;
          currP = head;
          while(currP != NULL){ 

            if (currP->key == z) {
              if (prevP == NULL) {
                head = currP->next;
              } else{
                prevP->next = currP->next;
              }
              temp = currP;
              currP = currP->next;
              delete temp;
              numberofnodes--;
            }
           else
           {
               prevP = currP;
               currP = currP->next;
           }
          }
          return;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider what happens when you remove the first entry in the list: You set `head = currP->next` but you leave `prevP` as `NULL`. When the code gets to `currP=prevP`, `currP` becomes `NULL`, and then you will hit an error trying to access `currP->next` in the iteration. You will need to reorganize your loop to avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

Your pointer management on moving to next iteration on a for-loop is incorrect. When `currP` is set to NULL on deleting the first item you will dereference NULL on the iteration increment step of the for-loop.

Honestly, a for-loop isn't the hottest idea for this algorithm in the first place, but if you really want to do this with minimal effort a pointer-to-pointer solution makes short work of this task:

```
void mylist::remove(int z)
{
    Node **pp = &head;
    while (*pp)
    {
        if ((*pp)->key != z)
        {
            pp = &(*pp)->next;
        }
        else
        {
            Node *victim = *pp;
            *pp = victim->next;
            delete victim;
            --numberofnodes;
        }
    }
}
```

**How It Works**

The pointer-to-pointer `pp` holds the address of the pointer we're interested in checking for a match. This initially holds the address of the `head` pointer.

```
Node **pp = &head;
```

With each non-match we move to the address of the current node's `next` pointer:

```
if ((*pp)->key != z)
{
    pp = &(*pp)->next;
}
```

but, when we discover a match the pointer value who's address is held in `pp` is saved to a temporary:

```
Node *victim = *pp;
```

then *that* pointer (which may be the `head` pointer if this is the first item in the list), is updated to its pointed-to-node's `next` pointer value.

```
*pp = victim->next;
```

Finally, the now-unlinked node is discarded.

```
delete victim;
```

**Notes:**

There is *NO* movement to `next` when we discard a match. We already moved there by loading `*pp` with the pointer value held in its own `next` pointer right before the deletion. Also, it is (hopefully obviously) **critical** that the `head` pointer be NULL if the list is empty, and the last node `next` pointer is `NULL` to terminate the list. Standard linked list stuff, I know, but it is important and therefore mentioned.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

consider you delete 1 in your list.
prevP = NULL;
then you delete currP and assigned it with prevP, witch is NULL.
end of this loop.
Then the it goes to the part of : prevP = currP, currP = currP->next;
latter case the problem, because currP is NULL. You are accessing NULL->next.

Answer (score 0):

delete currP;
currP=prevP;

This is causing segmentation fault , at first iteration prevP is null so if is executed in case iteration prevP is not Null.

Comment: okay, makes sense. How would I go about changing my code to do that? not sure.

Comment: prevPcurrentP;
delete currP;